# Rails 4 - Receive Text and Find Email Associated with the User that Texted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm stuck on the best way to do this. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

My app receives text messages from clients (Twilio) and then creates an email to send to the coach (user) the client works with. I'm having an issue of finding the email of the coach (user) based on the client that sent the text. The texts are successfully saving, I'm just missing the email of the coach (aka user.email).

Users > Clients > Text_Messages

I can currently assume that all clients are only owned by own coach.

Here is the **text_messages_controller.rb** (I've omitted non-relevant code):

```
class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:receive]
  protect_from_forgery :except => ["receive"]

def receive
  @text_message=TextMessage.create!(content: params[:Body], phone: params[:From],     incoming_message: "true", sentstatus: "false")

  # missing code to extract user.email somehow

  if @text_message.save
    render nothing: true, status: 200
  else
    puts 'ERROR: company or customer couldn\'t be loaded' 
  end 
end  

private

def text_message_params
  params.require(:text_message).permit(:content, :scheduled_date, :client_id, :sentstatus, :phone)
end  

end
```

Here is the **text_message.rb** model (just in case):

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'date'

class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy

end
```

I thought I would be able to use the text_message.phone to match to the client.phone, use the client.user_id to get the user (by id) and finally extract the email from the selected user. Unfortunately, that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm making the assumption that Coach belongs_to Client. Sounds like first you have to find the Client. Maybe something like:

```
@client = Client.find_by(phone: params[:from])
```

Then find the coach email with:

@coach_email = @client.coach.email

Or if it is that a Client belongs to a User through a has_many association then it should still be:

```
@coach_email = @client.user.email
```